# PHP removing noise words regular expression with boundaries with ' character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, word-boundary

I'm attempting to remove noise words from a string, and I have what I believe is a good algorithm for it, but I'm running into a snag. Before I do my preg_replace I remove all punctuation except apostrophe ('). The I put it through this preg_replace:

```
$content = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', self::$noiseWords).')\b/','',$content);
```

Which works great, except for words that do indeed have that ' character. preg_replace seems to be treating that as a boundary character. This is a problem for me.

Is there a way I can get around this? A different solution perhaps?

Thanks!

Here is the example I'm using:

```
$content = strtolower(strip_tags($content));
    $content = preg_replace("/(?!['])\p{P}/u", "", $content);// remove punctuation
    echo $content;// i've added striptags for editing as well should still workyep it doesnbsp

    $content = preg_replace("/\b(?<')(".implode('|', self::$noiseWords).")(?!')\b/",'',$content);

    $contentArray = explode(" ", $content);

    print_r($contentArray);
```

On the 3rd line you'll see the comment of what $content is right before the preg_replace

And though I'm assuming you can guess what my noiseWords array looks like, here's just a small fraction of it:

```
$noiseWords = array("a", "able","about","above","abroad","according","accordingly","across",
        "actually","adj","after","afterwards","again",......)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind and positive lookahead to make sure you're not "around" a quote character:

```
$regex = "/\b(?<!')(".implode('|', self::$noiseWords).")(?!')\b/";
```

Now, your regex will not match anything that is preceded by or following with a single quote.

Comment: Well I did this:

`$content = strtolower(strip_tags($content));

  $content = preg_replace("/(?!['])\p{P}/u", "", $content);// remove punctuation

  
  $content = preg_replace("/\b(?<')(".implode('|', self::$noiseWords).")(?!')\b/",'',$content);
  
  $contentArray = explode(" ", $content);
  
  print_r($contentArray);`

And now there is nothing in $contentArray at all. Everything got taken out.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a sample of what's in `$content` before you do anything to it?

Comment: Assuming `I` is one of your noise words, it looks like it's working for me. [Without my change](http://regexr.com?31md1) - [With my change](http://regexr.com?31md4).

Comment: Hmm yes, it appears to be working there. Yet, in my browser when I run the script I get nothing. Even just echoing $content before exploding it, it is an empty string

Comment: Actually in your second link: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31md4 it is not matching anything for me. Not working.

Comment: It looks like my copy/paste missed an exclamation mark. Check [this demo](http://regexr.com?31mda). It's now matching `I`, since I is a noise word, but it's not matching `I'm` and `'I`, which is making the single quote in those two examples not act like a word boundary.